# Add or Sum of hours like 13:30+00:00:20=13:30:20 but how?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, datetime

I want to add seconds (00:00:02) or minutes (00:00:20) on datetime value (may be stored string type) but how? Examples:

```
13:30+02:02:02= 15:32:02 ,
13:30+00:00:01= 13:30:01 ,
13:30+00:01:00=13:31:00 or 13:30 (not important)
```

Can you help me? I need your cool algorithm :) Thanks again...

Comment: Hi, unfortunately from your example it is not clear what you are after which is why there is not a good answer yet. If you try and display some more of the code you have, or give a brief outline of what you are actually doing then someone may be able to help.

Comment: plzsendtehcodez question. (See "I need your cool algorithm" and his subsequent 'response').

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you choose to use the TimeSpan, be aware about the Days part:

```
TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse("23:30");
TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:40:00");
TimeSpan t3 = t1.Add(t2);
Console.WriteLine(t3); // 1.00:10:00
```

With DateTime:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("23:30");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("00:40:00");
DateTime d3 = d1.Add(d2.TimeOfDay); 
Console.WriteLine(d3.TimeOfDay); // 00:10:00
```

Answer (score 9):

```
myDateTimeVariable.Add(new TimeSpan(2,2,2));
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding two datetimes from strings:

```
var result = DateTime.Parse(firstDate) + DateTime.Parse(secondDate);
```

Adding a string time to a datetime:

```
var result = existingDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(stringTime);
```

Adding time as in your example:

```
var result = TimeSpan.Parse("12:30:22") + TimeSpan.Parse("11:20:22");
```

Finally, your example as dates (not tested!):

```
var result = DateTime.Parse("12:30:22") + DateTime.Parse("11:20:22");
```

Note that this is sloppy coding, but you get the idea. You need to verify somehow that the string is actually parseable.

Comment: Solution: 
 TimeSpan a = TimeSpan.Parse("12:30:22") + TimeSpan.Parse("11:20:22");
            Console.Write(a.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
Thanks everyBody! i love Stackoverflow...

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure what you're after, but can you not just use the built in functions to C#'s DateTime object?

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;

myDate = myDate.AddHours(1);
myDate = myDate.AddMinutes(30);
myDate = myDate.AddSeconds(45);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is more abstract. As already mentioned, in .NET there are two types - `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`. The `DateTime` type represents a specific point in time. It's not an interval of time. It's a specific location in all time since the birth of the Universe. Even if you set the year/month/day components to 0, it will still represent some absolute point in time. Not a length of time.

The `TimeSpan` on the other hand represents some interval. 1 minute, 2 days, whatever. It's not specified WHEN, just HOW LONG.

So if you were to subtract two DateTime objects you would get a TimeSpan object that specifies how much time there is between them. And if you add a TimeSpan to a DateTime you get another DateTime. But you can't add a DateTime to another DateTime - that would make no sense.

It sounds to me like you should be working with `TimeSpan`s all the time, because you are dealing with lengths of time, not absolute points in time. If you get these lengths from your source as a DateTime then that's actually not correct, and you should convert them to `TimeSpan`s somehow. The parsing method is one way that has been suggested, but you might also try to subtract zero `DateTime` from it. That might be faster and more culture-independant.

Answer (score 1):

use the TimeSpan structure. you can add TimeSpans together, or you can add a TimeSpan to a DateTime to produce a new DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx). This converts a string to a TimeSpan object. That way you can do stuff like

```
TimeSpan a = TimeSpan.Parse(timeStringA)+TimeSpan.Parse(TimeStringB);
```

To split a string like "00:00:20+00:01:00" look at [string.split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
stringA = timeSting.split('+')[0];
stringb = timeSting.split('+')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", mytimespan.Hours 
    + (mytimespan.Days*24),mytimespan.Minutes,mytimespan.Seconds);
```

Comment: At StackOverflow please don't just paste code, but also explain your approach. In this specific case you may also want to explain what your late answer adds to the answers already given (and accepted).

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String timeText = "3/23/2015 12:00:13 AM"; 
        String timeText2 = "3/23/2015 1:45:03 AM"; 

        DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(timeText);
        string temp = time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        DateTime time2 = Convert.ToDateTime(timeText2);
        string temp2 = time2.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse(temp);
        TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse(temp2);

        Console.Out.WriteLine(t1 + t2);  // 01:45:16

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```