# Adding time as int

Tags: c#

Hello I am quite new to C# and I am facing difficulty in adding time as an int . For example,

```
01:30 Hr
09:45 Hr
13:27 Hr
```

are hours. I want to convert these to minutes.
How do I add these as int so that I get:

```
90 + 585 + 825
```

Is there a way to perform this operation in C#?

```
public int total_time;

void Start()
{
  total_time = time_1 + time_2 + time_3;
}
```

Comment: A floating point is a number with a decimal value (or the capacity for one, at least).  I only see integers here.  Are you actually adding any decimal values?  Or are you looking for a way to convert different formats of time (1:30 == 90)?

Comment: Consider using DateTime and DateTimeOffset classes ?

Comment: My aim is to convert the hours into minutes and then add those minutes. For example, 1hr 5mins is 65minutes, similarly 1hr 30minutes is 90 minutes. So i want to add 65+90. And you are right it is not float, it should be int.

Comment: How do you currently store the time? What data structure are you using to represent for example 1hr 5mins?

Comment: Please, post a [mre]. What is `13:27 Hr`? Is it a string? A DateTime? A TimeSpan?

Comment: since your int values seem to be minutes why not simply `total_time = (time_1 + time_2 + time_3) / 60;` ? ^^ It won't provide any fractals of an hour though .. only the full hours

Comment: I actually am storing the time to string.  @derHugo Can you please provide an example? How do I convert any hour to minutes?

Comment: This would bring us back to @Magnetron 's comment ;) Please provide a reproducible example of exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add or Sum of hours like 13:30+00:00:20=13:30:20 but how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510778/add-or-sum-of-hours-like-1330000020-133020-but-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that your time data are stored in this way:

```cs
var dataSource = new List<string>
{
  "01:30 Hr",
  "09:45 Hr",
  "13:27 Hr"
};
```

Then all you need to do is to

- get ride of the `Hr` suffix
- convert them to `TimeSpan`
- sum their `TotalMinutes`

```cs
var total = dataSource
    .Select(data => data.Substring(0, 5))
    .Select(time => TimeSpan.Parse(time).TotalMinutes)
    .Sum();
```

Obviously this is a naive implementation and really fragile.

A more robust solution would use

- regex to get the time portion of the string
- use `TimeSpan`'s `TryParse` to avoid runtime exceptions in case of mailformed inputs.

---

*UPDATE*

Based on the comment of [Drag and Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6560478/drag-and-drop), here is an alternative which could give you better precision:

```cs
var total = dataSource
            .Select(data => data.Substring(0, 5))
            .Select(time => TimeSpan.Parse(time))
            .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (t1, t2) => t1 + t2)
            .TotalMinutes;
```

This approach could be used as well whenever you introduce seconds as well.
(You just need to adjust the `Substring` parameters.)

Comment: I think you should keep time TimeSpan for as long as you can. If those string had more precision that second. It will be lost by using TotalMinutes on individual TimeSpan  instead of the sum. But Summing TimeSpan is hard you can do `.Select(time => TimeSpan.Parse(time))
    .Sum().TotalMinutes`

Comment: @DragandDrop Unfortunately we can't use that, it will give us a compilation error: `'IEnumerable<TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum'`

Comment: @DragandDrop `Aggregate` does work on the other hand. I've updated the post. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry I dropped the 'T' in "_.But Summing TimeSpan is hard you can do_". I meant It's had you can'**t** do this. But yeah you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0) struct? TimeSpan struct does exactly what you want.

```cs
TimeSpan thirtyMinute = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0); // Hours, Minutes, Seconds
TimeSpan s = new TimeSpan(1, 24, 60, 60, 100); // Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Miliseconds

TimeSpan oneHour = thirtyMinute + thirtyMinute; // You can add TimeSpan to another == 1 Hour
```

Here is how to convert hour string

```
Debug.Log(string.Format("You were out of game for: {0} minutes and {1:00} seconds", (int)totalExitTime / 60, (int)totalExitTime % 60));
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve exactly? If you explain why you are doing this in the first place, maybe we can help you more precisely.

Comment: @Richard if you want to describe a duration, or a time of day, Timespan is the way to go. Not sure what you mean by "random". A timespan is basically just a int64 with a bunch of methods to make it easier to work with.

Comment: Okay I will try this then. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally you should look into the [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime) .. usually you use these two in combination

Comment: @Richard I just edit my question last part. You can extend this for day or month too.

Comment: Perfect thank you. I shall test it now.

Comment: I actually like your method, but how do I get TimeSpan(1, 30, 0); as 90,  TimeSpan(09, 45, 0); as 585 ? Basically it should add up the hours + minutes to show in total minutes.

Comment: I do not want to display it as 00:00, I only want to add the hours as minutes, that is all.

Comment: var toMinute = new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0).TotalMinutes; // Will return 90 minutes
var toHour = new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0).TotalHours; // Will return 1.5 hours

Comment: Just use builtin TimeSpan methods. You can just get Minutes, TotalMinutes (Convert everything to minute), Hour, Day, second, milisecond.